# The argument type 'void Function(DioError)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(DioError, ErrorInterceptorHandler)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

so I'm wrapping my HTTP requests with a few simple functions. Like Following:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class HttpService {
  late Dio _dio;

  final String baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/community";

  HttpService() {
    _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
    ));

    // initializaInterceptors();
  }

  Future<Response> getRequest(String endPoint) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await _dio.get(endPoint);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }

    return response;
  }

  Future<Response> postRequest(String endPoint) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await _dio.post(endPoint);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }

    return response;
  }

  initializaInterceptors() {
      _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onError: (error) {
        print(error.message);
      }, onRequest: (request) {
        print("${request.method} ${request.path}");
      }, onResponse: (response) {
        print(response.data);
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine in the past months. However, it just pops an error in initializaInterceptors() function:

> The argument type 'void Function(DioError)' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'void Function(DioError, ErrorInterceptorHandler)?'.
> The argument type 'void Function(RequestOptions)' can't be assigned to
> the parameter type 'void Function(RequestOptions,
> RequestInterceptorHandler)?'. The argument type 'void
> Function(Response)' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'void Function(Response, ResponseInterceptorHandler)?'.

Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
initializeInterceptor(){
    _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
        onError: (error, errorInterceptorHandler ){
          print(error.message);
        },
        onRequest: (request, requestInterceptorHandler){
          print("${request.method} | ${request.path}");
        },
        onResponse: (response, responseInterceptorHandler) {
          print('${response.statusCode} ${response.statusCode} ${response.data}');
        }
    ));
  }
```