# How to pass onRequest in Interceptorwrapper

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

```
requestInterceptor(RequestOptions options) async {

options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
return options;
```

}

```
dio.interceptors.add(
  InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (RequestOptions options) => requestInterceptor(options),
  ),
);
```

before this was working fine but now the error is coming as error: The argument type 'dynamic Function(RequestOptions)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(RequestOptions, RequestInterceptorHandler)'
what I have to do if I add handler in the functions error: The argument type 'dynamic Function(RequestOptions)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(RequestOptions, RequestInterceptorHandler)' its too gives how to solve this
please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'void Function(DioError)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(DioError, ErrorInterceptorHandler)?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864120/the-argument-type-void-functiondioerror-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `RequestInterceptorHandler` in `onRequest` and send (next) the option to the hander.

```
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
     onRequest: (RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
        options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        return handler.next(options);
     }
));
```

Comment: no my mistake nothing to tell...it worked fine for me...and i'll do that what you said thanks